# Unable to launch a python script through my batch file

Tags: python, batch-file, console, cmd

I have a batch file that's supposed to set PATH/PYTHON path variables and then invoke my python script (myscript.py), that's designed as an interactive console. I tried with the following:

```
@echo off
setlocal

if not defined PYTHONHOME (echo warning: PYTHONHOME environment variable is not defined. Using C:\Python24 by default.
SET PYTHONHOME=C:\Python24
if not exist "C:\Python24" ( echo warning: C:\Python24 does not exists. Please specify PYTHONHOME variable manually.))

color 1e
set PYTHONSTARTUP=%~dp0%myscript.py
set PYTHONPATH=%~dp0;%PYTHONPATH%
path %PYTHONHOME%;%PATH%
set PATHEXT=%PATHEXT%;.PY
cd %~dp0%
cmd.exe /k title Interactive Python Console 1.0
cls
%~dp0%myscript.py"

:done
endlocal
```

Before setting the colorpair (1e)for the console, I have appended directory containing myscript to path, python path and python24 is set as python home.
My problem is:
I am able to change the default font/background color of console, set the current window's title, but then neither cls (clearscreen) works, nor does my script is invoked. At the console, my pwd is script's directory. But when i enter 'python' at the prompt, myscript is invoked and I can see interactive console of my script.
Anything missing from batch, that would automatically clear off the console after setting color/title, and invoke myscript.py?

Comment: Thank you for showing us the exact contents of your script. Could you double-check that that it is an accurate copy of the script?  For instance, `%~dp0%myscript.py"` has only one double-quote character. `set PYTHONPATH=%~dp0;%PYTHONPATH%` has no `%` between `%~dp0` and `;`.

Comment: That was a typo.. leftover from formatting..  But thanks for pointing out Jim! Actually the problem appropriately pointed out by Bren (below) was the script starting a new console. Removing cmd /k solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Python.  `cmd /k` doesn't "set the window title", it starts a *new* command shell and leaves you in it, thus stopping your script midway through.  Why don't you just do `title My New Title`?  There's no need to use `cmd`.